# Login screen in Windows store app - MessageDialog

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-8, messagedialog

I'm wondering, how to create login screen to looks like in picture below. It looks like MessageDialog, but I have no idea, how to achieve that kind of stuff. I was searching on net for this, but nothing usefull for total beginner as I am.

[image]

I know how to create MessageDialog, but don't know, how to add any textboxes to this dialog. Or maybe is this even not MessageDialog, but some kind of xaml file? As I say'd, i'm total beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [CredentialPicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701247.aspx) control.

There's an example of how to use it on [MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Credential-picker-sample-30fcba2e).

Comment: Can CredentialPicker be used for validation user from database?

Comment: Not directly, but you can create the picker in such a way that you can access the username/password and do the comparison yourself.

Comment: yes, but in this case the error string will not be shown on CredentialPicker, am i right?

Comment: Yes, i guess you do. :) So i will have to create my own "control"? Do you maybe know for any good tutorial for this? And thanks for help

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any other resources.  I only ever use the CredentialPicker and handle login failure myself, re-showing the picker if there's an error.  Also note that I've seen apps rejected from the store on the grounds of using a custom login dialog instead of the CredentialPicker (by no means all of them, but it does happen so be careful)

Comment: Realy? Hmm...ok I'll consider this and think about it realy carefully. Thanks again for all(sorry for bad english language:>)

Answer (score 1):

First of all. Do you need call this dialog or create your own similar like this?
If you need call this dialog than you should know that this is standart windows dialog and you can't add any additional fields. It shows when you call function XboxLIVEService.SignInAsync()
inother case - create your own user control